# How to manage fugitive commit with a git pre-commit hook?

Tags: git, plugin-fugitive

When working on a git project in vim, I use the [fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) plugin.

I like to open a `:Gstatus` split, press `-` to add file and then press `C` to commit my changes. I also have a git pre-commit hook, it runs some test. In case of an error, it prompts me
to make sure if I still want to commit.

But, when following this pattern, I don't see the output for the tests, neither the final prompt. Instead, vim freezes while the tests are running.

How would I make fugitive and a pre-commit hook get along together smoothly?

Update: This is the prompt in the git pre-commit hook:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec < /dev/tty

while true; do
  read -p "There were some errors in the test, do you still want to commit? (Y/n) " yn
  if [ "$yn" = "" ]; then
    yn='Y'
  fi
  case $yn in
      [Yy] ) break;;
      [Nn] ) exit;;
      * ) echo "Answer y or n.";;
  esac
done
```

Comment: I assume the `pre-commit` hook works fine when you just use `git commit`? What happens if you use a very simple `pre-commit` hook like only `exit 0` or `exit 1`?

Comment: It does work. It's really the output generated and the prompt.

Comment: As, so you mean "Vim freezes while the tests are running"? And not "Vim freezes indefinitely and I need to kill it"?

Comment: As soon as I press `C`, Vim goes to the terminal view and there is no output. I will add the part of the script which has the prompt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On line 1019 of `plugin/fugive.vim` we can see how the `:Gcommit` command executes `git`:

```
noautocmd silent execute '!'.command.' > '.outfile.' 2> '.errorfile
```

With the variables replaced, the command looks like:

```
!env GIT_EDITOR=false git --git-dir=/home/martin/git-test/.git commit  > /tmp/vC4Lbak/1 2> /tmp/vC4Lbak/2
```

Notice the `env GIT_EDITOR=false`, this is just to prepare the `.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG` and checking if any error occurred! We then open a new buffer with `COMMIT_EDITMSG` which the user can edit, and after this is saved, we run `git commit` again.

Fugitive also uses stderr for error checking, and the pre-commit hook outputs to stderr (not stdout!)

You could work around this by extensively modifying this function, but I would say that running interactive pre-commit hooks is incompatible with how `:Gcommit` works, the hook would be run twice, and you lose error detection.

So you'll have to run `git commit` from outside of Vim, or use `!git commit` from Vim which will work fine, except that it will launch a *second* Vim instance for the commit message (unless you use `-m`).

You can create a command for this like so:

```
:command! Commit !git commit
```